# How to get past "press a key to boot from cd" without a keyboard

Tags: boot

I have read many solutions online but I wasn't able to get my keyboard to work during boot. I want to reformat the PC, and I can use a very roundabout way to do so. Tricky part is, the computer does not boot right now.

So how can I get around pressing a key during boot?

Comment: If you’re referring to a Windows CD/DVD, this messages only appears when a bootable Windows installation is already present (don’t know the exact criteria though). In case you’re familiar with assembly, you could also modify the boot code not to show a message like this. This may be illegal, but nobody’s going to care.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: you can't.  Get this fixed.  Use a keyboard.

True answer: Actually, you might be able to.  There are tools that can update the system startup code (traditionally called "BIOS", but newer systems may use (U)EFI), and software that can restore or modify the settings (saved using CMOS).  The specific details may vary based on precisely what hardware (and perhaps some other details, like precisely which version of BIOS code) is being used.  For instance, software may need to be obtained by the motherboard manufacturer.  The solutions might, or might not, be sensibly easy to automate.

To have anywhere close to a decent chance at getting a more specific answer, we may need some more specific details, like which motherboard you are using, and perhaps what BIOS(/(U)EFI) version is currently installed.

Typically, the easiest/straightforward way (which, as a bonus, is a way that also tends to work on many different types of systems) is to obtain and use a working keyboard.

Comment: I managed to get the computer to boot. I am typing this on the keyboard that refuses to work during boot. I have tried this (and one other, functional keyboard) on every single usb port.

Answer (score 0):

In my BIOS setup, there’s a menu called “Integrated Peripherals” which had an option to enable keyboard support. After activating it, I can now use the keyboard during boot.